# Mizuno server throws a ClassNotFoundException: Jruby-opensslService on startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

I am porting a Ruby on Rails 3.2.8 app from MRI 1.9.3 to JRuby 1.6.7

The Rails app itself is JRuby friendly, I did have to jump through some hoops to get twitter-boot strap to work with JRuby. All of my tests pass and the app will run under *Webrick* (via `bundle exec rails server`).

When I attempt to run under [mizuno](https://github.com/matadon/mizuno), I get this odd error:

```
bundle exec mizuno -d
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Jruby-opensslService
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.jruby.util.JRubyClassLoader.findClass(JRubyClassLoader.java:86)
<a few thousands more lines>
```

(If you thought Java was bad, JRuby really knows how to spit some stack.)

I am sure you are thinking the same I was, but the Gemfile does include the *jruby-openssl*:

```
   bundle list | grep openssl
   * jruby-openssl (0.7.7)
```

My JRuby runtime, with no JRUBY_OPTS used:

```
jruby -v
jruby 1.6.7.2 (ruby-1.9.2-p312) (2012-05-01 26e08ba) (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_03) [linux-amd64-java]
```

Anyone with pearls of wisdom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to get mizuno to work using rackup:

```
bundle exec rackup -s mizuno
```